# Pandas - Filtering row based on value

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
col1,col2,value1,value2
type_1,type_2,,NaN
type_3,type_4,NaN,
type_5,type_6,apples,oranges
type_7,type_8,apples,apples
```

I am trying to filter out the above dataframe in which value1 is not the same as value2

Expected output:

```
col1,col2,value1,value2
type_1,type_2,,NaN
type_3,type_4,NaN,
type_5,type_6,apples,oranges
```

I have done the below:

```
df = df.query("value1 != value2")
```

I am having an issue where the rows with null and NaN get missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Since @WenYoBen mentioned it although your sample doesn't show that case. If your data have `NaN` on either `value1` or `value2` and you don't want to drop it. Belows will only drop on rows both `NaN`. I change 1 `NaN` of your sample to `pear` to show this case

```
df.query("value1 != value2").dropna(subset=['value1', 'value2'], how='all')

Out[3056]:
     col1    col2  value1   value2
0  type_1  type_2     NaN     pear
2  type_5  type_6  apples  oranges
```

`np.nan` compares against itself always return `False`. In other words, `np.nan != np.nan` returns `True`, so it will include in your output. If you need to filter it out, you just need adding `dropna` to the output:

```
df.query("value1 != value2").dropna()

Out[3035]:
     col1    col2  value1   value2
2  type_5  type_6  apples  oranges
```

Comment: @scottmartin NOTICE this will not work , when you have one columns is NaN other is not NaN, with dropna, you will drop that row , rather than keep it .

Comment: @WeNYoBen: thanks for mention that case. Please check updated

Comment: @AndyL. thanks that how I modified my case as mentioned

Comment: @scottmartin umm looks better

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways which you can do this:

## Using `boolean indexing`

I will use `.ne` here which stands for `not equal`

```
df[df['value1'].ne(df['value2'])]

     col1    col2  value1   value2
0  type_1  type_2     NaN      NaN
1  type_3  type_4     NaN      NaN
2  type_5  type_6  apples  oranges
```

---

## `.query`

```
df.query('value1 != value2')

     col1    col2  value1   value2
0  type_1  type_2     NaN      NaN
1  type_3  type_4     NaN      NaN
2  type_5  type_6  apples  oranges
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried the df.query way but I am trying to find rows where value1 != value2. As shown in my initial post, I have an empty cell in value1 and NaN in value2 and vice versa.. I am having issues filtering such rows

Comment: @scottmartin: have you tried `dropna` as in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you check with `np.nan`, you will find that `NaN` always not equal to `NaN`

```
np.nan==np.nan
Out[164]: False
```

So you may need  using

```
df[df.fillna('NaN').eval('value1!=value2')]
Out[170]: 
     col1    col2  value1   value2
0  type_1  type_2              NaN
1  type_3  type_4     NaN         
2  type_5  type_6  apples  oranges
```